# Can't build SSDL from the source code of the book C++ for the Lazy Programmers

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ssdl

I can't compile the SSDL [source code](https://github.com/Apress/cpp-for-lazy-programmers) from the book [C++ for the Lazy Programmers (2019)](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484251867) by Will Briggs on my ubuntu 20x so could you please tell me what goes wrong? I installed SDL2 and it's working but most of the cases I get the following error when I compile an SSDL code;

```
cpp-for-lazy-programmers/ch1/hello$ make -f Makefile.unix
g++ -c -g sdl2-config --cflags -I…/…/external/SSDL/include main.cpp -o main.o
In file included from …/…/external/SSDL/include/SSDL.h:27,
from main.cpp:7:
…/…/external/SSDL/include/SSDL_display.h:28:10: fatal error: SDL_ttf.h: No such file or directory
28 | #include <SDL_ttf.h>
| ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile.unix:60: main.o] Error 1
```

I just can't understand why SDL_ttf is a big issue as I see many posts regards to SDL_ttf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because they both have "SDL" in the name does not mean they are part of the same library.
If you search for `SDL_ttf.h` on packages.ubuntu.com ("contents of packages"), it will tell you that you want the [`libsdl2-ttf-dev` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/libsdl2-ttf-dev)

This is also mentioned in the [accompanying documentation](https://github.com/Apress/cpp-for-lazy-programmers/blob/master/GettingStarted.txt#L37).

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution accidentally jus after I'd posted my problem. I installed sdl but never thought ttf needed to be installed separately. I did what you referred to.